# Trouble using thin server - its not reloading content after modification

Tags: ruby, nginx, thin

I am trying to deploy a rack based application built with Roda gem to a VPS. I am using NGINX with Thin. The thing is, even after making changes to the files and restarting the thin server, it is still showing the content from old ruby files. And for some reason, if I check after many hours, it starts showing content from the new files. I am surprised about how it can show content from a file which has already been deleted/modified and doesn't have that content at all.

This is my Thin config file:

```
user: root
group: root
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
timeout: 30
wait: 30
log: var/log/thin/thin.log
max_conns: 1024
require: []
environment: production
max_persistent_conns: 512
servers: 2
onebyone: true
threaded: true
no-epoll: true
daemonize: true
socket: tmp/sockets/thin.sock
chdir: /var/www/mysite
tag: mysite
```

This is my nginx config file:

```
upstream mysite{
  ip_hash;
  server unix:/var/www/mysite/tmp/sockets/thin.0.sock max_fails=1 fail_timeout=15s;
  server unix:/var/www/mysite/tmp/sockets/thin.1.sock max_fails=1 fail_timeout=15s;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  root /var/www/mysite/public;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

}
```

Or does it have anything to do with NGINX?

Comment: I have never used Thin but I would expect to see the behavior you are experiencing when there is caching going on. Sounds like your cache expired after a couple hours at which point the latest changes to your code are reflected in your application... Also from your configuration it seems like you may have 2 Thin servers, are both being restarted?

Comment: Thanks rii. I had directly started the server on the folder than through the config file so the port was being occupied. After i cleared the port and restarted the server using the config file, it worked fine.

Comment: Great to hear, glad I could hint you in the right direction ;)